# What is this book about a juvenile detention centre that exists out of time?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember once reading a book about a boy who was for whatever reason summoned to this juvenile delinquency centre that existed outside the normal time frame and sentenced to remain there fore 300 years or so. The inmates do not age and when they return home, only a few minutes have passed

[Spoilers]

> He then later breaks out, with his friends by somehow commandeering the time ship or whatever it is that they use to get in and out, although if I recall, one of them ends up being left behind. (I also remember there being a love interest between the protagonist and the one left behind)

I think I remember a couple details, such as the fact that the prison building was doughnut-shaped and movement between the parts of the building was over walkways in the gap. I believe the cover (of the paperback edition I read, at least) was also white tiled with something written on them in red.

I've been trying to find the name and author of this book to recommend it to a friend, and I can not find it, any information at all you may have would be invaluable to me.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YearInsideHourOutside

Comment: I'll accept it when it lets me in 2 days' time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE: I've found the name of the book.

It's "The Traitors" by Tom Becker. I'll leave this here in case anyone else finds it by google search, but I'll close this question up for now.

[image: Book cover]

[Blurb from Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Traitors-Tom-Becker/dp/1407109529/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8):

> Adam Wilson is kidnapped and taken to the Dial after betraying his best friend. The Dial is a twilight world where teenage traitors are forced to atone for their treachery. It's a terrible place, ruled over by a cruel despot, where every day is a struggle for survival - and escape. Legend has it that only one person has fled the Colditz-like prison. Nobody knows if he made it back to the real world, but he left behind a ray of hope that has reached through the years. Soon Adam is caught up in a deadly plan to escape. But who can he trust in a world full of traitors...?

Comment: Great answer! And good sleuthing skills. Could you add a source for the blurb?

Comment: Source has been added - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Traitors-Tom-Becker/dp/1407109529/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8